# Saving file name as `BLOB` in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

While I'm sending file ( type="file") to database (PHPmyAdmin), instead of saving with file name it saves as  `BLOB` as shown in the following figure.

[image]

I found the the similar question [Saving Files as blob in database ajax php pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622293/saving-files-as-blob-in-database-ajax-php-pdo)
 here but didn't help me. My `php` code is as follows for sending file to the database.

```
       $info = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
       $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
       $newname = $get.".".$ext;  //$newname='newfilename.'.$ext     
       $target ="folder/".$newname;
       $doc= move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);         
       $sql="INSERT INTO apply(mobile,doc,position) 
             VALUES (' $mobile','$newname',' $position')";  
       $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

The file is sending to target folder (named folder) with the correct required name but Why I'm not getting the same name in the database. What's going wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the datatype of the table column in question.

Comment: currently my data type is `BLOB`.Which data type is suggestible to save files in DB?

Comment: You don't store files in a database. You store __paths to files__ in a database. So it is definitely a char/varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not tore files into the database directly because of critical performance issues.

Suggested way is to store files in file system, and store their path in database as `TEXT` or `Varchar`.

**Now coming to your question:**

> While I'm sending file ( type="file") to database (PHPmyAdmin), instead of saving with file name it saves as  BLOB as shown in the following figure.

Every file is composed of binaries but in different order and format. Storing it in database is not actually tricky. Database converts them into array of bytes/ stream of bytes and then stores these byte format data into the table.

When a fetch query is fired, it returns the exact byte stream in response. And at application level, these bytes are treated as files by their respective encoding techniques.

It's worth reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414551/what-is-it-exactly-a-blob-in-a-dbms-context) and subsequent link in the accepted answer.